# Get the Covariance returns for a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like this:

```
                   YAU        OTBL         HLE
2009-03-08         nan         nan         nan
2009-03-09  1.59904743  1.66397210  1.67345829
2009-03-10 -0.37065629 -0.36541822 -0.36015840
2009-03-11 -0.41055669  0.60004777  0.00536958
```

This is my function.

```
def get_covariance_returns(returns):
   return np.cov(returns.values)
```

returns parameter is a DataFrame Returns for each ticker and date.
The output is a 2 dimensional Ndarray The covariance of the returns.

When I run my code I have:

```
AssertionError: Wrong shape for output returns_covariance. Got (4, 4), expected (3, 3)
```

Now, I modified my function like this:

```
def get_covariance_returns(returns):
    return np.cov(returns.values, rowvar=False)
```

My result is:

```
OUTPUT returns_covariance:
[[ nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan]]
```

Please note that the expected output is:

```
EXPECTED OUTPUT FOR returns_covariance:
[[ 0.89856076  0.7205586   0.8458721 ]
 [ 0.7205586   0.78707297  0.76450378]
 [ 0.8458721   0.76450378  0.83182775]]
```

I need a guide to know what's wrong with my implementation, please. I am programming in Python language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`np.cov`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) if you drop the `NaN`s:

```
>>> np.cov(df.dropna().values, rowvar=False)
array([[ 1.31997225,  1.01614032,  1.2238726 ],
       [ 1.01614032,  1.0304141 ,  1.04243784],
       [ 1.2238726 ,  1.04243784,  1.17528792]])
```

Or more simply, use [`pandas` `.cov`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cov.html) which automatically exculdes `NaN`:

```
>>> df.cov()
           YAU      OTBL       HLE
YAU   1.319972  1.016140  1.223873
OTBL  1.016140  1.030414  1.042438
HLE   1.223873  1.042438  1.175288
```

**[EDIT]:** Based on your expected output, you are actually replacing `NaN` for Zero:

```
>>> np.cov(df.replace(np.nan, 0).values, rowvar=False)
array([[ 0.89856076,  0.7205586 ,  0.8458721 ],
       [ 0.7205586 ,  0.78707297,  0.76450378],
       [ 0.8458721 ,  0.76450378,  0.83182775]])

>>> df.replace(np.nan, 0).cov()
           YAU      OTBL       HLE
YAU   0.898561  0.720559  0.845872
OTBL  0.720559  0.787073  0.764504
HLE   0.845872  0.764504  0.831828
```

I'll leave my original post anyways because it shows a distinction between the two `cov` functions

Comment: Also: `df.fillna(0).cov()`